# I am trying to make a virtual assistant and I keep getting the error: "builtins.NameError: name 'r' is not defined" even though I defined r

Tags: python, voice-recognition

I am trying to make a virtual assistant and I used tech with tim's base code https://www.techwithtim.net/tutorials/voice-assistant/. I tried to make the assistant ask you for your name and then say How are you name. It gives me a weird variable not defined error, but I defined it.
Here is my code:

```
import os
import time
import playsound
from playsound import *
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS
import pyaudio
import time

def speak(text):
    tts = gTTS(text=text, lang="en")
    filename = "voice.mp3"
    tts.save(filename)
    playsound(filename)


def get_audio():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        said = ""

        try:
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(said)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception: " + str(e))

    return said

text = get_audio()

if "hello" in text:
    speak("hello, what is your name?")
    name = r.recognize_google(audio)
    time.sleep(1)
    ("How are you", name)
    if "good" in text:
        speak("Great! My name is bot by the way!")
time.sleep(99)
```

The error I get is:

```
builtins.NameError: name 'r' is not defined
```

Comment: Heres a video about global variables https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fc0XRcRmBP4

Comment: Please improve your question by making a shorter heading, and providing more details  like what you have tried, and what line the error is reported at.

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you define r it is a local variable.
This means that when the function finishes the variable gets deleted.

What you want to do is return the variable r when the function finishes.

Like this

```
import os
import time
import playsound
from playsound import *
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS
import pyaudio
import time

def speak(text):
    tts = gTTS(text=text, lang="en")
    filename = "voice.mp3"
    tts.save(filename)
    playsound(filename)


def get_audio():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        said = ""

        try:
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(said)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception: " + str(e))

    return said, r, audio
text, r, audio = get_audio()


if "hello" in text:
    speak("hello, what is your name?")
    name = r.recognize_google(audio)
    time.sleep(1)
    ("How are you", name)
    if "good" in text:
        speak("Great! My name is bot by the way!")
time.sleep(99)
```

Comment: I will try this

Comment: Now I get the error ```builtins.NameError: name 'audio' is not defined```

Comment: That will be the same error as r it is assigned in the function but not outside , you should watch this video about global vs local variables: youtube.com/watch?v=Fc0XRcRmBP4 The same fix will work as the fix for r

Comment: I have updated the code so that it should work with the audio variable

Comment: it does not speak my name when i say it